# Suggested template file is not working for Custom Search's template

Tags: 7, theming, bootstrap-theme

I have installed [Custom Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search) module for my drupal7 setup.

I am trying to modify template files for search-result and search-results.

By default its using template files from contrib module's theme itself which are as follows:

```
sites/all/modules/contrib/custom_search/theme/custom_search-results.tpl.php
sites/all/modules/contrib/custom_search/theme/custom_search-result.tpl.php
```

As per the theme-debug's hook suggestions I have created tpl files and have placed them within my sub-theme's templates directory, which are as follows:

```
sites/all/themes/bootstrap_sub/templates/custom-search-result.tpl.php
sites/all/themes/bootstrap_sub/templates/custom-search-results.tpl.php
```

I have cleared cache for several times, and still it uses template files from the module's theme directory.

Can anyone please help me out with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Your templates have all dashes whereas the module's templates have an underscore and a dash, e.g. `custom_search-result.tpl.php` (which seems odd) but I am guessing you need to copy these verbatim.

Comment: @danny-englander I have tried it, but it did not work.

Comment: Did you clear cache?

Comment: Yes, I have cleared cache using both drush and from admin UI (/admin/config/development/performance)

Comment: This looks like it's a known issue, see this for more info with solutions. https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search/issues/1162604

Comment: @danny-englander had to use search-result.tpl.php

Comment: ok I added the answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search/issues/1162604) with the Custom Search module for Drupal 7. Of note from the issue:

> Copy custom_search/theme/custom_search-result.tpl.php to your theme
>   location (e.g, sites/themes//templates/search-result.tpl.php), modify
>   accordingly and then refresh your caches.
>
> Tested on the current stable - custom_search 7.x-1.11

The solution is to rename `custom_search-result.tpl.php` from the module to `search-result.tpl.php` in your theme.